# Passing around the Redux context in actions and React components

Tags: reactjs, architecture, redux, reusability

Suppose I have a relatively complex React component that lets Redux handle its state but which I want to reuse in two different places. To me it seems logical that both instances should have a separate place in the Redux state tree.

I have read many discussions that seemed to address this problem of having reusable components using Redux and I am starting to have a feeling that there is not one proven approach that would solve it and isn't unnecessarily complex. Or I am getting completely lost.

There is one idea that I had but I am very cautious with it, because I feel that I am missing something. It goes like this:

- Pass the **Redux context** to React components (I am using ImmutableJS, so if I had a component NewEventModal inside DashboardPage, the context could be ['pages', 'dashboard', 'modals', 'newEvent'])
- All actions would carry the **Redux context**, in which they should be processed

To avoid polluting the code when passing the context from component to component, instead of props I would prefer to use the [React context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) to  pass this **Redux context**. I know, this is not recommended, unfortunately.

My question that I would like to direct onto more experienced Redux/React devs is, what do you think are the problems with this approach? Are there other approaches and libraries that would solve it in a similar fashion?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue but it sounds to me like you're talking about one component that you create two different containers from: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html.  i.e. have separate mapDispatchToProps and mapStateToProps function for each situation.

Comment: Yes, but imagine that the actions and reducer is complex. I don't want to copy paste the same action creators and reducer. I know I could make something like action creator-creator and reducer-creator which I could then use twice but that, IMO, would make the code unreadable.